# Weighing Scales connected by RS232 to USB keeps disconnecting

Tags: putty, serial, rs232, com

i have some weighing scales with a serial port (RS232) and are connected to Windows 10 PC with a Serial to USB Cable.

The scales are detected (COM3) and drivers are installed correctly, and im able to read data through PuTTY.

The problem is if any USB is plugged in, it stops the scales from working even though COM3 still shows as connected.

Can anyone think what would cause this? And is there any CMD scripts etc.. i can use to disconnect / reconnect COM ports correctly

Thanks for any help

Comment: There are lots of crappy cables out there. Many have fake or cloned chipsets. That is likely the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any cables you suggest?